# How to use count & distinct together for all columns

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I am getting error while executing the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct *) AS "total unique records" FROM table
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL server then currently it doesn't support multiple distinct columns for count. You can only use one distinct column name inside count function
Example : Select COUNT(distinct CountryCode) from Country

Comment: Surendra,What would be the procedure to get the count of distinct records of all columns

Answer (score 1):

Because `*` is not allowed there.  If you want to do this, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct t.*
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  After executing the query as per above, getting the unique records count  equal to total records count (with out using the distinct)  `SELECT COUNT(*) AS "total records" FROM table`

Comment: @vineel . . . This answers the question that you asked, which is about *distinct* records.  If you want total records, then you don't need to ask a question, because you seem to know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want :

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct t.*
      from table t
    ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code too count row

```html
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords FROM table
```

AND use that too count row and return order columns

```html
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRecords,* FROM table
```